# How to select an attribute based on string value within a group

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Table name:  Copies

```
+------------------------------------+
|   group_id  |  my_id  |  stuff     |  
+------------------------------------+

|     900    |    1     |      Y     | 
|     900    |    2     |      N     | 
|     901    |    3     |      Y     | 
|     901    |    4     |      Y     | 
|     902    |    5     |      N     | 
|     902    |    6     |      N     | 
|     903    |    7     |      N     | 
|     903    |    8     |      Y     | 
---------------------------------------
```

The output should be:

```
+------------------------------------+
|   group_id  |  my_id  |  stuff     |  
+------------------------------------+
|     900    |    1     |      Y     | 
|     903    |    8     |      Y     | 
--------------------------------------
```

Hello, I have a table where I have to discern a 'good' record within a group_id based on a positive (Y) value within the stuff field.  I need the full record where only one value fits this criteria.  If both stuff values are Y or both are N, then they shouldn't be selected.  It seems like this should be simple, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: So, the input rows always come in pairs, and "stuff" is NOT NULL?

Comment: apologies, there are some groups > 2.  If one record has stuff is null, and the others stuff='N', then neither should be returned.  If all records in a group are null, nothing from that group should be returned.

Comment: So what if there are two with Y, two with N and one with NULL? Or one with Y, two with N - etc.? Please do not answer by way of comment; instead, edit your post and clarify the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

One option here is to use conditional aggregation over each `group_id` and retain a group if it has a mixture of yes and no answers.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT group_id
    FROM Copies
    GROUP BY group_id
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN stuff = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
           SUM(CASE WHEN stuff = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
)

SELECT c1.*
FROM Copies c1
INNER JOIN cte c2
    ON c1.group_id = c2.group_id
WHERE c1.stuff = 'Y'
```

One advantage of this solution is that it will show *all* columns of matching records.

Comment: The requirement was to select all three columns, not just the `group_id`.

Comment: Hello, I tried to run this, and it gave me ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

Comment: @user7002207 - one obvious thing to try first is to delete the `;` right at the beginning - that is not Oracle syntax.

Comment: @user7002207 Sorry, I didn't see your exact requirement that you only want the yes records.  Just add a `WHERE` clause to my query.

Answer (score 1):

```
select group_id, 
       min(my_id) 
          keep (dense_rank first order by case stuff when 'Y' then 0 end) as my_id, 
       'Y' as stuff
from   table_1
group by group_id
having min(stuff) != max(stuff)
```

Comment: how could I get this to show all attributes in the table (other then just these 3)?

Comment: Same way - for each of them, add `min(attribute_column) keep (dense_rank first order by case stuff when 'Y' then 0 end) as attribute_column`. Since for each pair there is just one row with `'Y'`, the `min()` is over just one row, so it's just the value (the "attribute") - but the Oracle compiler doesn't know what you know, so it does require `min()` (even though YOU know it is not needed).

Comment: Sorry, I may have miscommunicated.  Is there way to do a select * based on this query.  there are about 50 attributes for each record in my real table.

Comment: @user7002207 - no, you can't - you must group, and when you group you must use aggregate functions. You can use select \* with other solutions, but they will be less efficient. Besides, you need to clarify the requirement, since it is not clear if ANY of the solutions offered here will work in your REAL problem (where rows do NOT come in pairs).

Answer (score 0):

```
with rows as(
select group_id, my_id, sum(case when stuff = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) c 
  from copies 
  group by group_id, my_id)
select c.* 
  from copies c inner join rows r on (c.group_id = r.group_id and c.my_id = r.my_id) 
  where r.c = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM copies t1
JOIN (
   SELECT group_id
   FROM copies 
   GROUP BY group_id
   HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN stuff = 'Y' THEN 1 END) = 1 AND 
          COUNT(CASE WHEN stuff = 'N' THEN 1 END) = 1
) t2 ON t1.group_id = t2.group_id
WHERE t1.stuff = 'Y'
```

This works as long as `group_id` values appear in couples.

Comment: But it wouldn't be hard to extend your query, you'd only need to tweak the `HAVING` clause a bit.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - in any case, it is hard to see why this problem would require a join-based approach - especially one that also does the aggregation that should suffice by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT C.*
FROM COPIES C,
     COPIES C2
WHERE C.STUFF='Y'    
AND C2.STUFF='N'
AND C.GROUP_ID=C2.GROUP_ID
```